# bundle exec -> undefined method `skip_authorization_check' for SessionsController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

I've just installed the 'sidekiq' gem and trying to run the following from the Terminal:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

When I run this though, I get the following error. This error does not occur when running the Rails server or loading the environment in the console.

```
undefined method `skip_authorization_check' for SessionsController:Class
```

It makes me think that the sidekiq script is trying to do something and it can't see that method. But I've not been able to make much progress with this.

Any clues?

Comment: Thanks Mike, you can see the backtrace here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/h254yjqmx119xnn/backtrace.txt

Comment: The backtrace doesn't help me.  The Cancan extension isn't being injected into the Controller for some reason.